# Remote SDK starting rails server exits while ssh cli session starts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shell, ssh

I'm working on a headless VM and configured my hosts Rubymine to use the remote SDK through the NAT interface of VirtualBox.

After configuring the remote SDK, my Run/Debug configuration looks fine. When I start the server, it returns the following output

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e '$stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift)' /home/user/project/bin/rails server -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000 -e development
git://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails.git (at master@06852de) is not yet checked out. Run `bundle install` first.

Process finished with exit code 11
```

When I fire up the same command, ssh'ed into the VM the server starts fine

The SDK seems to work; it invokes `/usr/bin/ruby` which is the proper path (no rvm)

The installed `gem` lib should be alright since everything works in ssh command line

The relevant lines in the `Gemfile` are

```
gem 'sprockets-rails', github: 'rails/sprockets-rails'
ruby '2.3.1'
gem 'rails', '~> 4.2'
```

The gems are installed in `~/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/bin/`

The advice of the output to run `bundle install` is useless, since I did and works anyway in cli. It seems like Rubymine needs adjustments. Has anyone an idea what I could do about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer!

Reason is the non-interactive shell session which sources less of your dotfiles (See `man bash` and search for `non-interactive`)

I knew it has nothing to do with Rubymine when I tried on my host system:

```
ssh user@127.0.0.1 "/usr/bin/ruby /home/user/project/bin/rails server -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000 -e development"
```

which provides the same output as Rubymine did

also check `ssh user@127.0.0.1 "env"` to see variables of your shell environment.

`man sshd 8` says how to set the environment, using the `~/.ssh/environment` (file on the server, since man page is sshd) to store `key/value` pairs like `KEY=value`

> This file is read into the environment at login (if it exists). It can
>   only contain empty lines, comment lines (that start with ‘#’), and
>   assignment lines of the form name=value. The file should be writable
>   only by the user; it need not be readable by anyone else.  Environment
>   processing is disabled by default and is controlled via the
>   PermitUserEnvironment option.

Note the `PermitUserEnvironment` option, goes into your `sshd.conf` on the server